Correct Water Heater Expansion Tank Pressure for Varying Supply Pressure & Bad? PRV
This is my first installation of an expansion tank in almost 5 decades of DIY plumbing. So I read a boat load about setting the correct pressure, but no posts addressed my situation.
My townhouse is served by a 2" water line, has a sprinkler system on a 1" line with a permanently installed pressure gauge that I've seen at 160 psi and 200 psi, I don't recall ever seeing any in between pressures. The household plumbing is all CPVC and I'd describe my water pressure as crappy for all the usual reasons. I just replaced the builder's 24-year-old 75-gal electric water heater with a 65-gal hybrid, so I want to protect this baby. There was no prior expansion tank which is now required by code. I installed a pressure gauge before the heater swap and it initially read ~52 psi but the red peaker needle hit 95 psi. Obviously, I have a pressure reducing valve and my understanding is that while these reduce pressure, they probably aren't sophisticated enough to regulate it.
Right before turning the water back on after the heater swap (with newly installed expansion tank,) I spot checked the pressure which seemed to be 60 psi with the sprinkler pressure at 200 psi. So I set the expansion tank pressure at 60 psi. After 48 hours of use and monitoring, the peaker needle hit 85 psi and I am concerned that this is on this on the high side and will reduce my heaters longevity.
I'm wondering if I should replace the PRV, that sucker is over $100 and no rebuild kits are available. Or is there a water pressure regulator I should put in line. When I search on water pressure regulators, all I get are PRVs and reading about them I'm not sure if they do regulate or just reduce (proportionally) the supply pressure. I haven't collected enough data to equate 52 psi reduced to 160 supplied and 60 psi reduced to 200 supplied, I'm working on that. So I'm not sure if the tank pressure should be closer to 50 or 60 or set in between. And the spike worries me.

What size (volume)  is the expansion tank?

Some table I saw said for my tank size and line pressure to get the 4.5 gal tank, so that is what I installed. Thanks for the info on the REGULATOR. I'm just not sure it is doing its job. If I am in the shower and the wife starts a load of laundry, the flow to the shower drops significantly.

There may be a restriction in the line. One common problem is crud from the outside pipes collecting at the strainer that is usually built into the input side of the PRV to keep its internal valves happy.

A PRV is a pressure regulator. However, a pressure regulator does not work the way you appear to assume (raising and lowering the output pressure - it simply lets water through when the output pressure is below the setpoint. When pressure is at or above the setpoint, it's a closed valve, and has no way to reduce the output pressure. You have to use some water for the pressure to be reduced below the setpoint so the valve opens and the regulator regulates it. It should not care if the incoming water pressure is 160 or 200 PSI if it is the right regulator for your situation - all it cares about is 52 PSI on the output.
That is exactly why the expansion tank is required. When the water heater fills with cold water, and water use stops, the expansion of the cold water heating results in the pressure rising - it will rise considerably less with an expansion tank in the system, as that contains a nice compressible bubble of air, rather than only incompressible water.
Set the expansion tank pre-charge (before installation, or with the plumbing drained to zero PSI) to 52 PSI as your PRV appears to be set at 52 PSI. You want it to be full of air at your regulated pressure, so it has the full capacity it was built with to use for expansion with minimal (not zero) pressure rise above the set point. If the PRV is set to 52 and the precharge is 60, you have 8 PSI were the expansion tank will do nothing for you. A second or larger expansion tank will reduce the extent of the pressure rise. Check the base pressure with a faucet slightly open somewhere so you get the steady-state regulated pressure.
Your water heater that you are concerned about is all-but-certainly rated for 150 PSI anyway, so 85 won't bother it. The usual component that fails on pressures over 80 is toilet fill valves. When your PRV really fails, the pressure (and temperature) relief valve on the water heater will let you know by spewing water, as your input pressure is above 150 PSI.
Note that depending on where the gauge with the high-reading needle is, the needle may be showing pressure spikes resulting from water hammer, not thermal expansion.
